# Proving a subgraph is regular

Tags: graph-theory

Given positive integer *k*, let *H* be the subgraph of Q_{2k+1} (a 2k+1 cube) induced by the vertices in which the number of ones and zeros differs by 1. Prove that *H* is regular and compute the order and size of *H*.

Honestly don't really know where to begin here. If someone could guide me in the right direction I would really appreciate it.

Comment: A $2k+1$ *what* cube?

Comment: Hypercube I guess? I'm not quite sure...we just work with regular n-cubes, but here, n=2k+1...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ease up notation let's put $n = 2k + 1$, and remember that $n$ is odd.

The vertices of $Q_n$ are all the $2^n$ strings of zeroes and ones.

Two types of such vertices go in $H$ : those that have $\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor$ zeroes and $\lceil \frac{n}{2} \rceil$ ones, or vice-versa.  Focus on the former.
In how many ways can you have $\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor$ zeroes in $n$ positions ?
It's the same for strings with more zeroes than ones, so double that and you get the order of $H$.

Now take some vertex $v \in V(H)$, and suppose wlog that $v$ has $\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor$ zeroes and $\lceil \frac{n}{2} \rceil$ ones.  In $Q_n$, the $n$ neighbors of $v$ are those that differ by exactly one digit.  When we restrict this condition to the vertices of $H$, the only way to find such a neighbor is to switch a one of $v$ for a zero (Why ?).  The number of such digits you can flip gives you the degree of $v$.